# How to get tabBarController in one of its viewController when using storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I make a **Tabbed Application** using storyboard template, **two** view controllers are embedded.

This is what I want to do: **in the first viewController, let TabBar to select the second viewController programmatically.**

The first viewController is a tableViewController, shows a list of items, and each item will push to a detailViewController. In the detailViewController, I edit some information and save the item. Then I want app to show the second ViewController, which is a tableViewController shows saved item.

Usually, we can use `[TabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];` to select the second viewController.

However, since this is a storyboard template application, so many code are hidden behind. So I cannot get the TabBar instance in the first viewController, and use **setSelectedIndex** method.

This is what confuses me...

And now, I have found the solution for this problem. My answer is below.

Comment: What do u want to say...?

Comment: where do you call `self.tabBarController`?

Comment: @Honghao Zhang - If you are using storyboard then you don't need to maintain viewcontroller heirarchy via code - Just study tabbar controller template code provided in xcode - you will got the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out how to solve this problem.

First I add new a class: **MyTabBarController**.

Then, in **storyboard**, select the Tab Bar Controller, in **identity inspector** panel, set the **custom class** to this new class.

For the first viewController class, add a property

`@property (nonatomic, weak) UITabBarController *tabBarController;`

Then add `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` in MyTabBarController class:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    FirstViewController *firstViewController = (FirstViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
    firstViewController.tabBarController = self;
```

In this way, I pass the tabBarController instance to the firstViewController, so, in the firstViewController, I can call `[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];`

Storyboard gives me a visual interface, however, it hides so many things behind.